# Remove duplicates from dropdown list

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to generate a `<select>` dropdown list of subclassifications to create a filter. When the list is generated I get duplicates and strings. How do I split the strings and then remove duplicates?

**EXAMPLE - This is what I current get**

```
<select data-filter="" class="form-control" name="subClassifications">
    <option value="all">Select sub-classification</option>
      <option value="Audit">Audit</option>
      <option value="Assurance,Accounting,Audit">Assurance,Accounting,Audit</option>
</select>
```

Path: `helper.js`

```
subClassificationsFilter() {
  let subClassifications = ProfessionalOverview.find( {}, { fields: { subclassification: 1 } } );

  if ( subClassifications ) {
    return _.uniq( subClassifications.map( ( subClassification ) => {
      return subClassification.subclassification;
    }), true );
  }
},
```

Comment: What I've got listed above plus, I've tried adding in things like `.split variables` however this seems to create arrays. I'm a little stumped as to how I group all the subclassifications together, split them up and then remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    subClassificationsFilter() {
        let subClassifications = ProfessionalOverview.find( {}, { fields: { subclassification: 1 } } ).fetch();
        let subClassification = _.map(subClassifications, function(obj) {
            return obj.subclassification;
        });

        let groupSubClassification = _.flatten(subClassification);

        return _.uniq(groupSubClassification).sort();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a list to remove duplicates

```
unorderedList = Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key){
    return {label: key, value: myObject[key]}
});
```

Then order the unordered list

```
const orderedList = {};
Object.keys(unorderedList).sort().forEach(function(key) {
    orderedList[key] = unorderedList[key];
});
```

Use the ordered list to create your dropdown.

Comment: Thank Bruno, that would have worked well however I was able to use underscore instead. Thanks heaps for your suggestion.